# GAS View Execution Transcript / Logs window not updating / clearing?

Tags: google-apps-script

I ran a script last night and checked the execution transcript window and the script had worked. Later I ran another script and viewed the execution transcript window and it showed the transcript of the previously run script. I was using Chrome Version 19.0.1084.52. I tried again using the latest version of Firefox Version 18.0.2 and had the same result.

This morning I decided to clear the cache and cookies in Chrome and try again. When I loaded Chrome, it indicated that there had been a 'Sync' issue with synchronising my data (browser history, bookmarks etc.) with my Google account. I disabled synchronisation, cleared the cache and cookies, and quit Chrome. I reloaded Chrome, logged in and opened my script project. Out of curiosity, I viewed the execution transcript window and it still had the transcript from the script I had successfully run last night. Surely the transcript / logs windows should be cleared when one runs a new script or signs out?

### Explanation / Scenario

I have a GAS script project which contains several script files Code.gs, Test.gs, RemoveLabels.gs, CreateLabels.gs. I want to put try...catch blocks in my script named CreateLabels.gs. It will create new labels in Gmail. I created a new script file named ErrorTest.gs so I could try out one of the examples in the Mozilla Developer Network Javascript Reference documents for throwing an error - [throw - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw).

I copied the example under 'Throw an object' from the page (it tests for an invalid month number) into my new script file and it works as expected.

In my script file CreateLabels.gs, I have put the following code:

```
function UserException(message) {
  this.message = message;
  this.name = "UserException";
};
```

and in the function I want to throw an error, I have:

```
function getDayTable() {
  var myTable = new Object();
  var values = g_ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(2, 5, 2).getValues();
  throw new UserException('Cannot access the spreadsheet');
  values[0] [0] == "" ? myTable.year = 2005 : myTable.year = values[0] [0];
  values[1] [0] == "" ? myTable.day = 1 : myTable.day = values [1] [0];
  return myTable;
};
```

In my code calling the function, I have:

```
try {
  var dayTable = getDayTable();

  //throws an error if dayTable cannot be retrieved
} catch (e) {
  Logger.log('There has been an error!');
  logMyErrors_(e); //pass exception object to error handler
}
```

I run the script named CreateLabels.gs and the execution transcript window still has the transcript from the previous run file named ErrorTest.gs. Does trying to run two script files under the same project, one after the other cause a problem?

Comment: So neither the transcript or the logs windows are being updated? or is it just the transcript window?

Comment: Both windows are not being updated.

Comment: Is the name of the function that you're running the same in each script file? Example, are you running `main()` in CreateLabels.gs and `main()` in ErrorTest.gs?

Comment: @Phil - Yes. Both CreateLabels.gs and ErrorTest.gs have functions named 'myFunction()' and within those functions they each have the 'UserException()' function. I select myFunction to run the scripts.

Comment: That would be the issue. Function names must be unique across all files. You cannot have 2 functions with the same name, even though they may be in separate files.

Comment: @Phil - I did'nt realise that. I have now changed the function name in CreateLabels.gs and I have deleted ErrorTest.gs. I have tried running CreateLabels.gs and it is working fine. Thanks for your help.